# I am having trouble with adding items to my list in python

Tags: python

Just like the title says I am having trouble adding items to a list for some reason. I am sure it is something simple, but just to make sure.

```
fnamesfile = open('fnames.txt','w')
global fnames
fnames = ['spanish.db', 'biology.db', 'dictionary.db']
def choose():
    global filename
    print "\nEXISTING FILES:"
    for i in fnames:
        print i
    print "\nFOR NEW FILE ENTER NEW NAME:"
    choice = raw_input('Open: ')
    choicedb = "%s.db" % choice
    if choicedb in fnames:
        filename = shelve.open(choicedb)
    else:
        choice = raw_input("ARE YOU SURE YOU WANT TO MAKE NEW FILE?[y/n] ")
        if choice == 'y':
            fnames.append(choicedb)
            filename = shelve.open(choicedb)
        elif choice == 'n':
            choose()
```

Comment: fnames is not in the scope of your function choose. Meaning you can access it but CANNOT modify it. I'd recommend getting rid of global variables

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? What happens? Do you get an error? Print the current list and what you are putting into it right before ill fated operation.

Comment: `global fnames` should be inside the function

Comment: @preezzzy `fnames` is a list. OP doesn't rebind `fnames` itself. Modifying a mutable object this was is okay.

Comment: Sayone can't change "fnames" inside the function is rubbish. Please, check how the language works in fact before emmiting an opinion. The more likely here is that the program is being terminated before doing anything with the modified list.

Comment: @jsbueno I already mentioned that. lets not start flaming.

Comment: what exactly is the problem you are facing? I ran your code and it appends to the list just fine.

Comment: Just to keep things from getting too confusing, unlike @jsbueno's claim, because `fnames` is not marked `global` inside the function, you can't change it. You can change the mutable object it refences but you cannot reassign a different value to it. For instance, were `fnames` a string instead of a list, `fnames += 'something'` would not work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to both import the shelves library and actually make a call to your function.

```
import shelve
fnames = ['spanish.db', 'biology.db', 'dictionary.db']
def choose():
    print fnames # for debugging
    global filename
    print "\nEXISTING FILES:"
    for i in fnames:
        print i
    print "\nFOR NEW FILE ENTER NEW NAME:"
    choice = raw_input('Open: ')
    choicedb = "%s.db" % choice
    if choicedb in fnames:
        filename = shelve.open(choicedb)
    else:
        choice = raw_input("ARE YOU SURE YOU WANT TO MAKE NEW FILE?[y/n] ")
        if choice == 'y':
            fnames.append(choicedb)
            filename = shelve.open(choicedb)
        elif choice == 'n':
            choose()
    print fnames # for debugging

choose()
```

The first and last `print` statements I am leaving in there for you so you can see it working, but you should remove them after you are satisfied that it's working.

Comment: Are you sure OP wasn't just posting a portion of the actual script?

Comment: I am not, but based on what OP did post, changing these two things makes the function work as OP said it should.

Comment: Its certainly possible that this is the answer. I am puzzled by the original poster who goes dark and won't answer questions. Then our answers would have less guess work.